# Refining bash script with multiple find regex sed awk to array and functions that build a report

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

The following code is working, but it takes too long and everything I've tried to reduce it bombs either due to white spaces, inconsistent access.log syntax or something else.

Any suggestions to help cut down the finds to one `find $LOGS -mtime -30 -type f - print0 and grep/sed/awk/sort` **once** compared to multiple finds like this would be appreciated:

```
find $LOGS -mtime -30 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -B 2 -w "RESULT err=0 tag=97" | grep -w "BIND" | sed '/uid=/!d;s//&\n/;s/.*\n//;:a;/,/bb;$!{n;ba};:b;s//\n&/;P;D' | sed 's/ //g' | sed s/$/,/g |awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a)print i a[i]}' |sort -t , -k 2 -g > $OUTPUT1;

find $LOGS -mtime -30 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -B 2 -w "RESULT err=0 tag=97" | grep -E 'BIND|LDAP connection from*' | sed '/from /!d;s//&\n/;s/.*\n//;:a;/:/bb;$!{n;ba};:b;s//\n&/;P;D' | sed 's/ //g' | sed s/$/,/g |awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a)print i a[i]}' |sort -t , -k 2 -g > $IPAUTH0;

find $LOGS -mtime -30 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -B 2 -w "RESULT err=49 tag=97" | grep -w "BIND" | sed '/uid=/!d;s//&\n/;s/.*\n//;:a;/,/bb;$!{n;ba};:b;s//\n&/;P;D' | sed 's/ //g' | sed s/$/,/g |awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a)print i a[i]}' |sort -t , -k 2 -g > $OUTPUT2;
```

I've tried: `for find | while read -r file; do grep1>output1 grep2>output2 grep3>output3 done` and a few others, but cannot seem to get the syntax right and am hoping to cut down the repeats here.

The full script (stripped of some content) can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/wxfBwTZe) and runs against a Java program I wrote for an email report. NOTE: This runs against access logs in about 60GB of combined text.

Comment: @l0b0 Over a decade reading, but first time posting, go gentle on me hehe. You can delete it and I can attempt to repost with markdown and a more simple set

Comment: It's better if you modify the question rather than deleting it.

Comment: @l0b0 blam. Hopefully a lot cleaner.

Comment: The long `sed` expression seems to be wrong. It contains a part `s//&\n/` but this is invallid as you cannot repace an empty string.

Comment: What should this expression do?  `sed '/uid=/!d;s//&\n/;s/.*\n//;:a;/,/bb;$!{n;ba};:b;s//\n&/;P;D'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked closely at the `sed`/`awk`/etc section (and they'll be hard to work on without some example data), but you should be able to share the initial scans by `grep`ing for lines matching *any* of the patterns, storing that in a temp file, and then searching just that for the individual patterns. I'd also use `find ... -exec` instead of `find ... | xargs`:

```
tempfile=$(mktemp "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/logextract.XXXXXX") || {
    echo "Error creating temp file" >&2
    exit 1
}
find $LOGS -mtime -30 -type f -exec grep -B 2 -Ew "RESULT err=(0|49) tag=97" {} + >"$tempfile"
grep -B 2 -w "RESULT err=0 tag=97" "$tempfile" | grep -w "BIND" | ...
grep -B 2 -w "RESULT err=0 tag=97" "$tempfile" | grep -E 'BIND|LDAP connection from*' | ...
grep -B 2 -w "RESULT err=49 tag=97" "$tempfile" | grep -w "BIND" | ...
rm "$tempfile"
```

BTW, you probably don't mean to search for `LDAP connection from*` -- the `from*` at the end means "fro" followed by 0 or more "m" characters.

A couple of general scripting recommendations: use lower- or mixed-case variables to avoid accidental conflicts with the various all-caps names that have special meanings. (Except when you *want* the special meaning, e.g. setting `PATH`.)

Also, putting double-quotes around variable references is generally a good idea to prevent unexpected word splitting and wildcard expansion... except that in some places your script depends on this, like setting `LOGS="/log_dump/ldap/c*"`, and then counting on wildcard expansion happening when the variable is used. In these cases, it's usually better to use a bash array to store each item (e.g. filename) as a separate element:

```
logs=(/log_dump/ldap/c*)   # Wildcard gets expanded when it's defined
...
find "${logs[@]}" -mtime ... # All that syntax gets all array elements in unmangled form
```

Note that this isn't really needed in cases like this where you know there aren't going to be any unexpected wildcards or spaces in the variable, but when you're dealing with unconstrained data this method is safer. (I work mostly on macOS, where spaces in filenames are just a fact of life, and I've learned the hard way to use script idioms that aren't confused by them.)

Comment: alright, so I modified it a bit based on your tempfile suggestion, which reduced the runtime by about 3 minutes. I also renamed my variables to include upper/lower case and spruced up some of the code locations. Have a look [here](https://pastebin.com/wxfBwTZe).

I had to add a `[[ -f /tmp/logextract ]] && rm -f "/tmp/logextract"` before mktemp ran or it bombs out with a :

` "mktemp: cannot create temp file /tmp/logextract: File exists"`. 

Easy fix though. Thank you for the input!

Comment: @c0mad0r Hmm, `mktemp` shouldn't be just using the same name every time, it should randomize it. Maybe your version doesn't use `-t` like I'm used to? I've edited my answer to a (hopefully) more reliable/portable form. Also, I forgot to recommend deleting the temp file after it's been used; I added that to my recommendation as well. BTW, you said this cut about 3 minutes off the runtime; what fraction of the total is that (just curious)?

Comment: Using RHEL6 VM, so not OVERLY old, but older. We're in the process of upgrading our LDAP OUD to RHEL8 right now actually and I'll have to test this there anyways. As for the total runtime: 26 minutes. It connects via 10GbE NFS mount to cull some 60GB of ldap access.log files and is expected to take a while. The $tmpfile once finished ends up being about 15.4GB total. I've considered doing this all via a database, but tbh, it's easier for me this way.

Comment: @c0mad0r It occurs to me that you might be able to get even more speedup by writing an `awk` script that looks for each of the three patterns, and outputs to 3 different temp files depending on which pattern matches (`awk` is smart enough to do things like this). But if you only got a ~10% speedup from doing a single `grep` scan, I suspect you won't gain much more this way.